# How to extract the first field/value on a json file using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file that has this content:

```json
{
  "Message": {
    "greeting": "hello"
  }
}
{
  "Message": {
    "greeting": "Bonjour"
  }
}
{
  "Message": {
    "greeting": "Konnichiwa"
  }
}
```

I would like to extract only the first Message that has `"greeting" : "hello"`.
I can't seem to use an index on it using

```
cat "$file" | jq -c "."
```

The above command all returns the three messages. I would like to ask on how to only extract the first message or one by one.

Comment: If your json is always indented that way, you could also do `sed '/^}/q' < thatfile` which would save having to read it fully or parse the json in there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You input file contains several JSON objects. Use `-s` to read them all into a single array, otherwise `jq` processes them one by one. Then, you can just print the first one by specifying its index:

```
jq -cs '.[0]'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need!

Comment: Or `jq -cs first`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you want the first JSON object which has a `greeting` key corresponding to the value `hello`, specifically, not just the first JSON object.

```bash
jq -s 'map(select(.Message.greeting == "hello")) | first' file.json
```

This reads the JSON objects in `file.json` into an array with `-s` (`--surp`).  This array is then filtered for any object that contains a `.Message.greeting` key with value `hello`.  The first of these objects is returned.

With a modified example document,

```json
{
  "Message": {
    "greeting": "Konnichiwa"
  }
}
{
  "Message": {
    "greeting": "hello",
    "id": 1
  }
}
{
  "Message": {
    "greeting": "hello",
    "id": 2
  }
}
{
  "Message": {
    "greeting": "Bonjour"
  }
}
```

where the `id` keys were added just to tell two otherwise identical objects apart,
the `jq` command returns

```json
{
  "Message": {
    "greeting": "hello",
    "id": 1
  }
}
```